# remap not working; <NL> in appears in other binding

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I'm trying to remap Control + [hjkl] to navigate among splits, by setting this in my rc file:

```
" splits navigation
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

However, `<C-h>` isn't working; it moves the cursor left a character, as if I had hit backspace (i.e. it traverses lines, unlike my `h`). The other movements work.

Asking (neo)vim for mapping information about `<C-h>` doesn't show anything suspicious looking:

```
:verbose map <C-h>
n  <C-H>         <C-W>h
        Last set from ~/workspace/dotfiles/.nvimrc
```

However, if I ask about `<C-j>` (which works as expected), it says that `<NL>` is involved?

```
:verbose map <C-j>
n  <NL>          <C-W>j
        Last set from ~/workspace/dotfiles/.nvimrc
```

Changing the order of my `nnoremap`s doesn't seem to change the behavior.

How should I debug this?

Comment: I don't know the details, so for now I'll just comment: I'm pretty sure this has to do with a special key code created with `<C-h>`. If you try it in a terminal, you will see a similar behaviour. Also see `:h backspace`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @KarlYngveLervåg. May be worth noting that I use the Dvorak keyboard layout, which places the "h" letter underneath the J key (the "j" letter is underneath the C key). I mention this because `:h backspace` notes that "<NL>" is related to "CTRL-J".

Comment: Worth trying as a workaround: `noremap     <C-h> <c-w><c-h>` (i.e. <c-h> instead of h) as they are equivalent

Comment: @jalanb replacing my `<C-h>` remap with your suggestion causes an audible bell, and no cursor movement. (Pressing `<C-w><C-h>` does work jump to the split to the left.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a [bug](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2048) in Neovim.

A suggested [workaround](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2048#issuecomment-78045837) in that bug is to run the following commands to adjust your terminal's terminfo entry to match what Neovim expects:

```
infocmp $TERM | sed 's/kbs=^[hH]/kbs=\\177/' > $TERM.ti
tic $TERM.ti
```

Comment: This got flagged as low quality. Perhaps you could add in the information in https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2048#issuecomment-78045837 which seems to have a workaround?

Comment: @mur Or close the question because it's likely not going to be useful long term.  vi.SE isn't a bug reporting forum.

Comment: From the question, it's not that obvious this is a bug... This question is probably flagged automatically because it's below a certain numbers of characters & has a link.