# Mapping control-H in insert mode doesn't work; it always works like backspace

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, terminal

I tried mapping control-H, J, K, and L respectively in insert mode to move around splits.

```
inoremap <C-h> <ESC><C-W><C-h>i 
inoremap <C-l> <ESC><C-W><C-l>i
```

When I press control L, it moves along fine, but when I press control H, it does a backspace.

My understanding is that control-H is backspace in terminal, which is why I can't do this. Is there any workaround? The following says that control h is not mapped

```
:verbose imap <C-h>
```

Comment: Related: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2484/remap-not-working-nl-in-appears-in-other-binding with workaround: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2520/67

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that many terminal emulators emit a `<C-h>` (0x08) when you press `<Backspace>`, there is no way for Vim to see if the user pressed Backspace, or `<C-h>`.

So one thing you can do, is remap the `<Backspace>` key:

```
inoremap <Backspace> <Esc><C-W><C-h>a
inoremap <C-l> <Esc><C-W><C-l>a
```

This should work are you expect, with the obvious downside that you've now lost your backspace key.

Not all is lost, there is also *another* common keycode for the backspace key: `<C-?>` (0x7f, or the `DEL` character). So you'll need to configure your terminal emulator to send that key instead.

For `xterm` setting `xterm.*backarrowKey: false` in `~/.Xdefaults` is usually enough, though the logic that xterm uses in deciding which character to send is quite complex, see the `backarrowKeyIsErase` in `xterm(1)` for more information.
You need to load this file with `xrdb ~/.Xdefaults` and open a new terminal window for this to take effect.

For other terminal emulators, the procedure will differ. For example in `gnome-terminal` you can configure this in `Edit -> Profile preferences -> Backspace key generates`.

Next, you want to tell Vim to accept `^?` as the backspace character with:

```
set t_kb=^?
```

Don't type `^?`, you need to insert the escape code, so use `<C-v>x7f` to insert it (or, if you've reloaded the terminal settings, pressing `<C-v><BS>` should also work).

You should now be able to remap `<C-h>`:

```
inoremap <C-h> <Esc><C-W><C-h>a
inoremap <C-l> <Esc><C-W><C-l>a
```

Related: [Mapping Ctrl+s does not work](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/mapping-ctrls-does-not-work)

Comment: There actually is a way to differentiate these keypresses in some terminal emulators (namely xterm and pangoterm).  The latter does it by default and xterm can be configured to do so.

Comment: @jamessan Thanks; do you happen to have some info on how to do this in xterm?

Comment: I used your gnome terminal instructions, so now the backspace key generates a "ASCII delete", and the backspace key still works fine. That part is good. The problem is, I can't seem to override the mapping of control h, I suspect because it still tries to handle it as a backspace-like thing