# Does <c-h> represent a backspace when being mapped?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I've been learning Vim recently and I decided to put a few lines in my vimrc for quick navigation without having to leave normal mode, like so:

```
inoremap jk <esc>
inoremap <c-h> <esc>i
inoremap <c-l> <esc>la
inoremap <c-k> <esc>ka
inoremap <c-j> <esc>ja
```

This ended up breaking my backspace key so that in insert mode, it only moved back one space without deleting the character. After a bit of looking around, I found that the `<c-h>` line was the culprit, due to it being connected somehow to backspace. Does this character combination represent the backspace key in all situations? Is there some way to map this without messing up backspace?

Comment: I closed your question as duplicate but feel free to edit and vote to reopen if you need more information. Also you can check [how do I debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3119/1841) I tried to create a canonical answer for mapping issues.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks!